# how to avoid a line overflow in the margin?

Tags: formatting, columns

Here is my problem, an overflow in the right margin, due probably to existing - at this location:
[image]

I have tried solutions depicted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64240/text-created-with-a-newcommand-overflows-into-margin-not-xspace-question), but the result is unchanged:

- `\emergencystretch=1em` in the preambul
- `\sloppy` in the preambul
- Local solution: `\renewcommand{\positionne-t-elle}{\texttt{position\-ne-t-elle}}` but I have the compilation error: *LaTeX Error: \positionne -t-elleundefined*.
- EDIT - Other local solution that works: posi`\-`tion`\-`ne-t-elle

Anyway, I would prefer a global solution.

And a LyX MWE:

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
I have a overflow-in-the-margin problem.
 Here is a hyphenation test with big composed words like-this-one, or this-other
-one to provoque a line-overflowinthemargin-Actuallyugly isn't it ?
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: LaTeX doesn't allow dashes in command sequences. I suspect the command `\positionne` is also not defined. Have you considered defining the allowed hyphenation for the word _positionetelle_ in the document preamble?

Comment: If Marc van Dongen's suggestion fails, could you provide a MWE (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am working with LyX. I have edited the question with a working local solution based on Mars's one. Here, it is a TeX box with \- in it at the right hyphenations places.

Comment: Use the german shortcuts of babel or define a shortcur `"=` for a hyoen which allows hyphenation on all position in a word: another"=word . Otherwise TeX will hyphenate another-word only at the hyphen.

Comment: Regarding bullet #3 (local solution), have you previously defined `\positionne-t-elle`? I.e.: should it be `\newcommand` instead of `\renewcommand`?

Comment: Herbert, I prefer solution 4 which enable to define several acceptable hyphenation instead of *on all position".

Comment: cslstr, in the other post (cf link), it seems they used a command name as a command and as a text example, which is confusing. I am not sure what to do: `\renewcommand{\DirectTransformation}{\texttt{Direct\-Transformation}}`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `babel` package  and  write `\babelhyphen{hard}` instead of the hyphen (in a ERT box if you are using Lyx). This can be simplified a bit using a macro:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\newcommand\fh{\babelhyphen{hard}}
\begin{document}
Have a overflow-in-the-margin problem.
Here is a hyphenation test with big composed words 
like-this-one, or this-other-one to provoque a line\fh 
overflowinthemargin\fh Actuallyugly isn't it ?
\end{document}
```

> [image: MWE]

For readability, yo can use a hyphen-like macro, but take care that `\-` or `\_` are already defined. Moreover  you cannot use `\newcommand` for this. But may be some like `\def\¬{\babelhyphen{hard}}` do not break anything.

Alternatively to a macro, you can define a shorthand trough babel commands:

```
\useshorthands*{"}
\defineshorthand{"-}{\babelhyphen{hard}}
```

The text is more readable  in this way (although  `"-` need also a ERT  box to avoid LyX transformation in two characters in the source code) but in any case be sure that this is what you want for all the languages in your document. Note that `\defineshorthand` allow optional arguments ito have a language dependent behaviour (texdoc babel, page 8).

Add also the `microtype` package. This solve most `Overfull \hbox` warnings without any intervention (but not always, as in this extreme example).

Comment: What is the difference please between `\-` and `\babelhyphen{hard} `?

Comment: @lalebarde `\babelhyphen{hard}` is a "hard hyphen", just like  `-`  but allow hyphenation in the rest of the word, whereas the original `\-` is a "soft hyphen", that is,  not a hyphen, but just a breaking opportunity. But `\-` could have have been redefined in some languages differently. The babel equivalent of the original `\-`  is the starred `\babelhyphen*{soft}`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried \linebreak?

Source: http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/breaking.htm